# choose a NIC (network interface card) for UDP listener

Tags: c#, forms, asynchronous, udp, nic

I would like to bind a NIC to listen to a specific port, from a specific IP address. I have set up an internal send/ receive process in my code for testing. I have managed to allow for configurable port value to listen on, and put in checks to make sure it only receives from a certain IP. My issue is that when I setup my endpoint as the NIC value, I can only receive messages sent to that IP. Perhaps my understanding of UDP is lacking, but what seems to be expected of me, is that I bind a NIC, to select it as my device on which the packet should be received, but it should be able to pick up a packet being sent on lets say a broadcast-ed IP. Maybe this is fundamentally wrong, but here is my code.

If it can't be done and the IP of the NIC has to be designated to be sent from sender side, please explain, otherwise can someone please advise me how to bind my NIC but still look to receive packets sent on other IP's.

so here is my receiver

```
public void StartListening()
    {
        if (init == true)
        {
            running = true;
            listenEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(Variables.NICIP, Variables.ListenPort);
            udp = new UdpClient(listenEndpoint);
            init = false;
        }

        if (running == true)
        {
            this.udp.BeginReceive(Receive, new object());
        }
    }
    private void Receive(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        IPEndPoint ip1 = null;
        byte[] bytes1 = null;

        if (running == true)
        {
            bytes1 = udp.EndReceive(ar, ref ip1);

            if (ip1.Address.Address == Variables.IPValue.Address)
            {
                string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes1);

                Submit = message;
                Console.WriteLine(message);

            }
        }
        StartListening();
    }

    public void Destructor()
    {
        running = false;
        udp.Close();

    }
```

and here is my makeshift sender

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Sender hereItComes = new Sender();
        hereItComes.Send();
    }
    public class Sender
    {
        public void Send()
        {
            UdpClient client = new UdpClient();

            IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(Variables.NICIP, Variables.ListenPort);
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Foo");
            client.Send(bytes, bytes.Length, ip);
            client.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally I would like to put any valid IP value into Variables.NICIP --> which is the IP of the NIC I designate, and that NIC would receive the packet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to determine if the address is multicast or not and then use something like JoinMulticastGroup. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient.joinmulticastgroup?view=netframework-4.7.2  for joining the group and then [How to check if an IP address is within a particular subnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499269/how-to-check-if-an-ip-address-is-within-a-particular-subnet) for determining if the address is multicast etc.

See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.enablebroadcast?view=netframework-4.7.2

If the multicast to unicast is being performed on the router than you do not need to join the group bit simply bind and listen and send to the designed address as you are already doing.

See the comments for versions of these methods I have wrote for use in my libraries.

P.s. Don't forget to leave the group if you join it as traffic will continue to be attempted to be delivered even after your socket is closed in most cases if you do not.

Don't forget if your sending anything back to use the DontRoute flag if you have multiple NICs.

Comment: See also https://github.com/juliusfriedman/net7mma/blob/master/Common/Extensions/SocketExtensions.cs and https://github.com/juliusfriedman/net7mma/blob/master/Common/Extensions/IPAddressExtensions.cs and https://github.com/juliusfriedman/net7mma/blob/master/Common/Extensions/NetworkInterfaceExtensions.cs

Comment: I may be wrong, but would this not require the sender to join said multicastgroup? The functionality I'm after is a previously decided port, with an unknown sending ip from the sender. I would like to be able to know nothing about the sender, except the port number, and not have to do anything specific to change the method in which it sends, this is because I may not have access to the sending methods. I guess i just want my NIC to look for any sent UDP on that port, much like if you had IPAddress.any instead of Variables.NICIP   .

Comment: If the sender is sending you multicast data then the sender must have joined the group to send it otherwise someone else has joined the group and is relaying the multicast data to you. You can listen to IPAddress.Any however you must also specify a port. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301134/how-to-receive-udp-packets-from-any-ip-and-any-port